# How to validate country code and mobile number

Tags: ios, swift, validation, country-codes, mobile-country-code

I have a registration page
in that I have mobile number field. Where, user can select country code from my 3rd party library (**MICountryPicker**), user will enter mobile number manually

now my question is, if user selected Kuwait country code & if he give Indian mobile number
I have to show some error message like "not valid mobile number"

Is there any library to validate both country code & mobile number ?

Comment: [Google libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS).

Answer (score -3):

[PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit)
a swift framework for parsing, formatting and validating international phone numbers.

Setup with coacopods

```
pod 'PhoneNumberKit'
```

Comment: in this user can't select country code from dropDown/list right ?